# Почему ul не в div

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Не могу найти косяк в верстке у  `<div class="base">` есть `border` внутри него `ul`,а на деле будто список вообще в блоке,не могу найти косяк.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="base">
    <div class="content_wrapper">

      <div id="itog">itog</div>
      <ul class="grid effect-2" id="responds">


        <li id="item_94">
          <div class="del_wrapper"><a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-94">X</a></div>
          <div id=note-94 class="edit">edit</div>
          <br><span class="head-94">загрузка</span><span class="text-94">загрузка</span>
        </li>
        <li id="item_93">
          <div class="del_wrapper"><a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-93">X</a></div>
          <div id=note-93 class="edit">edit</div>
          <br><span class="head-93">4</span><span class="text-93">4</span>
          <br>
        </li>
        <li id="item_92">
          <div class="del_wrapper"><a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-92">X</a></div>
          <div id=note-92 class="edit">edit</div>
          <br><span class="head-92">3</span><span class="text-92">3</span>
          <br>
        </li>
        <li id="item_91">
          <div class="del_wrapper"><a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-91">X</a></div>
          <div id=note-91 class="edit">edit</div>
          <br><span class="head-91">2</span><span class="text-91">2</span>
          <br>
        </li>
        <li id="item_90">
          <div class="del_wrapper"><a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-90">X</a></div>
          <div id=note-90 class="edit">edit</div>
          <br><span class="head-90">1</span><span class="text-90">1</span>
          <br>
        </li>
        <li id="item_89">
          <div class="del_wrapper"><a href="#" class="del_button" id="del-89">X</a></div>
          <div id=note-89 class="edit">edit</div>
          <br><span class="head-89">в</span><span class="text-89">в</span>
          <br>
        </li>



      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Весь пример https://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/da5othte/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас внутри блока содержатся элементы `li` с `float: left;`. Чтобы решить вашу проблему можете использовать `display: inline-block;` вместо `float: left;` или просто добавить `overflow: hidden;` блоку `grid`.